# How do you fix the array to make it right?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /* Hello! I didn't know if we had to use functions, because the assignment didn't say. Please tell me if you would like to resubmit and add functions.*/
    int num1=1, num2=2, num3=3, num4=4, num5=5, num6=6, i;
    for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
        if (num1=i) {
            num1=num1;
        }
        else if (num2=i) {
            num2=1;
            num2=num2*2;
        }
        else if (num3=i) {
            num3=1;
            num3=num2*2*2;
        }
        else if (num4=i) {
            num4=1;
            num4=num2*2*2*2;
        }
        else if (num5=i) {
            num5=1;
            num5=num2*2*2*2*2;
        }
        else if (num6=i) {
            num6=1;
            num6=num2*2*2*2*2*2;
        }
    }        

    int array[2][6] = {{num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6},{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    for (int row=0; row<2; row++) {

        for (int column=0; column<6; column++) {
            cout << array[2][6] << " ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    cout<<num1<<" "<<num2<<" "<<num3<<" "<<num4<<" "<<num5<<" "<<num6<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is supposed to return

```
1 2 4 8 16 32
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 4 16 32
```

Currently, it returns something very different... what do I do?

Also, I know this is a very inefficient way of doing this, so if you have a better way, I'm open to that as well. In this array, `2^i` is just stored in the i'th location.

Comment: `cout << array[2][6] << " ";`?? That's logically wrong and also undefined behavior

Comment: `if (num1=i)` should be `if (num1==i)`. Same thing everywhere else.

Comment: `cout << array[row][column]` instead of `cout << array[2][6]`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `num1=i` you should use `num1==i`. You have only two rows in array[2][6] and you want to print 3 rows so you should add another row with {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6} to array[2][6]. Replace `cout << array[2][6] << " ";` with 
`cout << array[row][column] << " ";`